# How to import JavaScript file in vite?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I tried to import the notifications.js file in App.jsx, but it didn't work.I am using React and Vite.

I tried using import "./notifications" in App.jsx and in the App.jsx file I used tag name notifications. I expected to view the arrays in the notifications.js.

Comment: Please share your folder structure and exact error

Comment: please provide [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or atleast some small snippet of your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to import something specific (like a function) from a JS file. First in your `notifications.js` file, you have to **export** such a function. Then in your `App.jsx` you import that function with the **import** statement like this:

`import { MyFunction } from "./notifications"`

or

`import MyFunction from "./notifications"` if the function is the default export.

You can read more about importing and exporting [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/importing-and-exporting-components)

Comment: The only problem s that I can not give it a name. In the notification.js is export default [list of arrays].